# sshpass exit in automation

Tags: shell, sshpass

I have total of 6 IP addresses and out of the 6 only 2 IP addresses are valid.  I wrote a shell script to use sshpass to test each IP.

The issue is when script reaches IP that is working it log's in the system (Cisco switch) and stays there and not continuing with the loop to test the remaining IPs.  If i type "exit" on the system than it continues with the loop.

After a successful login how can script automatically get out, from logged system, and continue with testing remaining IP?

/usr/bin/sshpass -p $ADMINPASS ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -t $ADMINLOGIN@$IP exit

i can use the exit status to figure out which IP worked and which on didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Test first if IP is alive, and then 'ssh' on it, could help you.I don't know if you are using a loop or not, but loop can be a good choice.Should look like : for f in ip-1 ip-2 ip-3 ip-4 ip-5 ip-6; do ping -c 1 -w 3 $f; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo OK; ssh_pass $f your_command; else echo " IP is NOK"; fi; done
You can then also add 'exit' command, depending on what you test : 'exit 0' if it is OK, after you 'ssh' command, 'exit 1' if NOK.